# Rendering block depending on block state/passing variable between classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, initialization, minecraft

I've created a wire block, custom rendered in Techne. What I want for happen is for parts of the wire to show/hide depending on whether or not another wire is connected. This is working in theory and worked when I manually inputted connectivity states. Now I'm actually trying to get the data the game crashes on loading the world due to an uninitialized boolean array containing the connectivity states. If anyone could help me with getting the data from the block class to the rendering class that would be great.

Block class

```
package foodTech.blocks;

import java.util.Random;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockContainer;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import foodTech.tileEntities.TileEntityCable;

public class BlockCable extends BlockContainer
{
    /**
     * Contains 6 values for each face of a cable block
     * up, down, north, south, east, west
     */
    public static boolean[] neighbourBlockWires;

    public BlockCable(Material material)
    {
        super(material);
        float pixel = 1F/16F;
        this.setBlockBounds(12*pixel/2, 12*pixel/2, 12*pixel/2, 1-12*pixel/2, 1-12*pixel/2, 1-12*pixel/2);
        this.useNeighborBrightness = true;
    }

    public int getRenderType()
    {
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean isOpaqueCube()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean renderAsNormalBlock()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public TileEntity createNewTileEntity(World world, int var2) 
    {
        return new TileEntityCable();
    }

     private void getConnectedWires(int x, int y, int z, World world)
     {
         boolean[] neighbourBlockWires = {false, false, false, false, false, false};

         if (world.getBlock(x, y+1, z).equals(this)) neighbourBlockWires[0] = true;
         if (world.getBlock(x, y-1, z).equals(this)) neighbourBlockWires[1] = true;
         if (world.getBlock(x+1, y, z).equals(this)) neighbourBlockWires[2] = true;
         if (world.getBlock(x-1, y, z).equals(this)) neighbourBlockWires[3] = true;
         if (world.getBlock(x, y, z+1).equals(this)) neighbourBlockWires[4] = true;
         if (world.getBlock(x, y, z-1).equals(this)) neighbourBlockWires[5] = true;

         BlockCable.neighbourBlockWires = neighbourBlockWires;
     }

     public void onNeighborBlockChange(World world, int x, int y, int z, Block block)
     {
         getConnectedWires(x, y, z, world);
     }

     public void updateTick(World world, int x, int y, int z, Random rand)
     {
         getConnectedWires(x, y, z, world);
     }

     public void onBlockAdded(World world, int x, int y, int z)
     {
         getConnectedWires(x, y, z, world);
     }
}
```

Rendering class

```
package foodTech.tileEntities.render;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.TileEntitySpecialRenderer;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import foodTech.blocks.BlockCable;
import foodTech.tileEntities.models.ModelCable;

public class RenderCable extends TileEntitySpecialRenderer 
{
    ResourceLocation textureOff = (new ResourceLocation("roboguy99:textures/models/cableOff.png"));
    ResourceLocation textureOn = (new ResourceLocation("roboguy99:textures/models/cableOn.png"));

    public ModelCable modelCable;
    private boolean[] neighbourBlockWires = {true, false, false, false, false, false};

    public RenderCable()
    {
        this.modelCable = new ModelCable(this.neighbourBlockWires);
    }

    public void renderTileEntityAt(TileEntity tileEntity, double x, double y, double z, float scale) 
    {
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef((float) x + 0.5F, (float) y - 0.5F, (float) z + 0.5F);

            Minecraft.getMinecraft().renderEngine.bindTexture(textureOff);

            this.neighbourBlockWires = BlockCable.neighbourBlockWires;
            this.modelCable = new ModelCable(this.neighbourBlockWires);

            this.modelCable.render((Entity)null, 0.0F, 0.0F, -0.1F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0625F);

            GL11.glTranslatef((float) x - 0.5F, (float) y + 0.5F, (float) z - 0.5F);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

If you need to see any more of my code I can upload it.

Answer (score 0):

> the game crashes on loading the world due to an uninitialized boolean array containing the connectivity states.

So initialise it. Like this:

```
public static boolean[] neighbourBlockWires = new boolean[6];
```

Though I really don't think it should be `static` unless you want every wire in the world to render in the exact same way.

Comment: I put this in the render class but got the same error in the same place.